# Highcharts: displaying data sets from one series

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to create a column highchart where I can compare 3 measures (e.g. x, y and z axes) attributed to each category on the x axis.  All the measures exist in the same dataframe, so I want to access them from the same series.

I understand that I am able to display one measure (when attributing it to 'y') and access the other measures by creating new variables like 'MyVal' into the point object (as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27892923/highcharts-adding-extra-data-to-drilldown/27893384#27893384)), but this only seems to give me the ability to access them in tooltip.  Is there anyway I can attribute each a variable and also display them all side by side (rather then just displaying 'y')

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is a very confusing question.

The `y` value tells the chart where to plot the data point in relation to the `yAxis`.

The y axis of a chart is simply the vertical axis (in most cases).

I assume that you are saying you want to simply plot your three values as three columns (but, again, it is unclear what you are actually trying to do); this is simply a matter of adding three data points to your data series - not adding three dimensions to your single data point.

You can do it as simply as:

```
series: [{
  data: [4,5,3]
}]
```

In conjunction with predefined categories, or by specifying the categories in the data:

```
series: [{
  data: [{
    'name': 'Measure 1',
    y: 4
  }, {
    'name': 'Measure 2',
    y: 5
  }, {
    'name': 'Measure 3',
    y: 3
  }]
}]
```

Fiddle example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/3d3fuhbb/208/

Output:

[image]

What else do you require?

**{{EDIT -**

Additional options:

1) grouped column

Fiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/3d3fuhbb/209/

Data structure:

```
series: [{
  name: 'Measures',
  data: [4]
},{
  name: 'Measure B',
  data: [5]
},{
  name: 'Measure C',
  data: [3]
}]
```

2) fiddle with the x placement, use single category:

Fiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/3d3fuhbb/211/

Data structure:

```
series: [{
  pointRange: 0.25,
  dataLabels: {
    enabled: true,
    formatter: function() {
      return this.point.name;
    }
  },
  data: [{
    'name': 'Measure 1',
    x: -0.25,
    y: 4
  }, {
    'name': 'Measure 2',
    x: 0,
    y: 5
  }, {
    'name': 'Measure 3',
    x: 0.25,
    y: 3
  }]
}]
```

3) skip the categories, hide the axis labels, use the x axis title in its place:

fiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/3d3fuhbb/212/

Data Structure:

```
series: [{
    dataLabels: {
    enabled: true,
    formatter: function() {
      return this.point.name;
    }
  },
  data: [{
    'name': 'Measure 1',
    y: 4
  }, {
    'name': 'Measure 2',
    y: 5
  }, {
    'name': 'Measure 3',
    y: 3
  }]
}]
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  I'm trying to do something more along the lines of this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/drilldown/multi-series/).  Where I have multiple columns that are contained within the one categories (ie, Democrats).  However, rather than referring to each measure individually as you have done above, I want to figure out if I can do something more like: data:[{ 'name': 'data', y:4, x:5, z:3}]

Comment: The short answer is still no, you can't do it like that. Specifying the data for a point is specifying the data for that point. You need to specify a data point for each data point that you want plotted...  But we can get just about anything you want with the right options. See updated answer for various options